# WCF Web Service returns "Bad Request" error when invoked through Javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf

I am trying to make an ajax GET request to a WCF web service method through javascript. The request returns with a 400 "Bad Request" error everytime. But if I invoke the same web service method through the WCF Test Client, it returns the correct results.

Also, the ajax call through javascript returns the bad request error on both GET and POST requests.

I have added the [WebGet] attribute to my web service method but the error still persists.

Here is my javascript method and ajax call:

```
function Getdata()
{
var methodUrl = serverUrl + "/GetData";
      $.ajax({
    async: false,
                 type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: methodUrl,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
    //ensures the results will be returned as JSON.
    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("ERROR: GetData() Check your browsers javascript console for more details." + " \n XmlHttpRequest: " + XmlHttpRequest + " \n textStatus: " + textStatus + " \n errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

Here, serverUrl is of the format: "http://hostname:portnumber/webServiceProxy.svc"

Any idea why the request would return a "Bad Request" error when invoked through javascript and work perfectly when invoked through the WCF Test Client? Any inputs will be appreciated! Thank you!

Also, I have compared the requests sent out from the WCF Test Client and from my AJAX request using Fiddler and here is what I see:

WCF Test Client Request:

```
POST http://hostname:portnumber/WebServiceProxy.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IWebServiceProxy/GetData"
Host: hostname:portnumber
Content-Length: 144
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

My AJAX Request:

```
GET http://hostname:portnumber/WebServiceProxy.svc/GetData HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Language: en-us
Referer: http://hostname/OrgName/WebResources/resourceName?pagemode=iframe
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E; BOIE9;ENUS)
```

Host: hostname:portnumber
    Connection: Keep-Alive

So the biggest difference that I see is that the WCF Test Client makes a POST request and sends the web service method name in a SOAP envelope while my ajax request is a GET and adds the web service method name to the url. Looking at these requests, any ideas on how I might have to change my ajax call to get it to work correctly? Thanks!

Editing to add my web.config file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDDSWCFService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://machinename:8080/DDSWCFService" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDDSWCFService" contract="WCFService.IDDSWCFService"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IDDSWCFService">
            <identity>

            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>

            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>

        </serviceBehaviors>

        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
                <enableWebScript/>
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing server configuration. Try to use Fiddler and compare requests from WCF Test Client and Ajax.

Comment: I have edited my question and deleted the comments to overcome the formatting issues.

Comment: Is that server file? I see only client configuration here. How do you host your service? There should be <services> element - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx and that service should contain  binding="webHttpBinding" in its endpoint.

Comment: @dharnitski

Right now I am just trying to test out the web service proxy so I am running the actual web service as a console app on my local machine and connecting to it through the proxy which is hosted on another machine. So the web config that I posted is for the proxy.

Comment: I need to SERVER config file and understand how do you host it. It seems that client code is OK but service does not support AJAX.

Comment: @dharnitski I have completely simplified my web service to just one method and posted all the code at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11022395/1081934
Can you please take a look and give me your inputs? Thank you!

Comment: I answered question in http://stackoverflow.com/q/11022395/1081934

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses. Surprisingly enough, I managed to fix the error, but the solution was totally not what I was expecting. I had to add an additional attribute to the markup of the Service1.svc file:

Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory

I am not sure why this wasn't automatically added to the file when the project was built, but thats what did it. I am now able to invoke the Test method through the browser as well as through my AJAX request with no problem.

Thanks again for everybody's help.

Answer (score 1):

> I see that the biggest difference between the WCF test client request
>   and my ajax request is that I make a GET request and pass in the name
>   of the web service method in the url while the WCF test client makes a
>   post request and sends in the web service method name in a SOAP
>   envelope.

Seems that your service is configured with SOAP binding and cannot work with AJAX Get requests.

You need to use `WebHttpBinding` if you want to consume your service from JS.

1. Add `[WebGet]` attribute got your operation
2. Change binding in your endpoint - `binding="webHttpBinding"`
3. Configure behavior for endpoint

There are many samples in internet. For example this one http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="webBehavior">
    <webHttp />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

You need to add service section to your web.config file. Host does not know that you want to use `webHttpBinding` unless you tell him.

```
<services>
  <service name="Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Link below provides detailed instructions for hosting service in IIS (with `wsHttpBinding`). You just need to use `webHttpBinding` instead of `wsHttpBinding` -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I tried this out, but I am still getting the same error. I came across a post that said if a service reference is added to the proxy, then there can be such issues but the solutions did not work for me. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Please add your server config file to question.

Comment: I have added my web.config contents to the question. Any inputs will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I hope your service is running in another domain from where you are consuming it. You have to use JSONP calls in those cases.

Modify the `dataType` to `jsonp`.

```
$.ajax({
  //..
  dataType: "jsonp",
  //..
});
```