# Ajax call to WCF Web Service returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: ajax, wcf, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF Web Service returns “Bad Request” error when invoked through Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986479/wcf-web-service-returns-bad-request-error-when-invoked-through-javascript)

I have a simple WCF web service Service1 with just one method Test() which returns a string. I have deployed this web service on a test machine, but when I try to invoke the Test method from the browser I simply get a 400 Bad Request error. The same happens when I try to invoke the method through an AJAX GET request. But surprisingly, the method returns the correct result when invoked through the WCFTestClient.

Here is the code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    // This method can be called to get a list of page sets per report.
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string Test();
}       

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

This is my AJAX request:

```
 var serverUrl1 = 'http://' + baseUrl + ':86/Service1.svc';

 function GetTestString()
 {
        var methodUrl = serverUrl1 + "/Test";
        $.ajax({
    async: false,
                type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
            url: methodUrl,
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        //ensures the results will be returned as JSON.
              XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                },
    success: function (data) {
        ShowQRGSlides(data.d);
    },
    error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("ERROR: GetAvailablePages() Check your browsers javascript console for more details." + " \n XmlHttpRequest: " + XmlHttpRequest + " \n textStatus: " + textStatus + " \n errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
  });

 }
```

Here is the web.config file for my web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

This is just the simple web.config which gets automatically generated. I am unable to figure out why this simple web service method is not accessible through the browser or ajax. The same method returns the result when accessed through the WCFTestClient.

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add service section to your web.config file. Host does not know that you want to use `webHttpBinding` unless you tell him.

```
<services>
  <service name="Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Link below provides detailed instructions for hosting service in IIS (with `wsHttpBinding`). You just need to use `webHttpBinding` instead of `wsHttpBinding` -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Comment: If I add the service section to the web.config file and then make a call to the Test method through the browser, I get 500 "Internal Server" error with an error message "The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch(mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)"